# copy data from the three tables into a fourth table

Tags: php, mysql

Trying to make an event registration site but get stuck by copying data from multiple tables into another table.

I have three tables with data called user, event & ticket.

tbl 1 called **user** with following fields: **UserID, FName, LName**

tbl 2 called **event** with following fields: **eventID, eventName, EventDescription**

tbl 3 called **ticket** with following fields: **ticketID, ticketName, ticketDescription, eventID** *(eventID from table 2)*

.

tbl 4 called **registration** with following fields:

**UserID, FName, FName, eventID, eventName, EventDescription, ticketID, ticketName, TicketDescription** *(UserID, FName, FName from logged in user)*

.

When a user login, he see all the upcoming events, he can choose one, and then the different tickets for that specific event show up.
When he choose a ticket, he get more information about that specific ticket + event.
If the user click on the registration button, a query should run which copy data from the three tables into a fourth table called registration. 

Can someone help me out here?

Regards, Benny

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use something like this ( On the assumption that you can join all 3 tables ) :

```
SELECT * INTO `registration` from (
  //SQL query that joins the first 3 tables and selects the col's u need.
)
```

Comment: Can't figure out how to join the tables.

Comment: Share the all the table col names with relationships.

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
select * into newtable from
( 
select * from table1
union all
select * from table2
union all
select * from table3
) A
```